# Expected ":"Pylance

Tags: python

I can't find where the missing ":" is.

My code is:

```
def A_star_Traversal(cost, heuristic, start_point, goals):
    path = []
    hashTable = {}
    for i in goals:
        hashTable[i] = 1
    n = len(cost)
    visited = [False for j in range (n)]
    pq = [[0+heuristic[0],start_point]]
    heapq.heapify(pq)
    while(len(pq)):
        v = heapq.heappop(pq)
        if(hashTable.get(v)):
            path.append(v)
            break
        visited[v] = True
        path.append(v)
        f=1
        for i in range n:     '''this is where i get the error'''
            if(visited[i]==False and cost[v][i]>0):
                pq.append([cost[v][i]+heuristic[i],i])
                heapq.heapify(pq)
                f=0
        if(f):
            path.pop()
    return path
```

I am getting the error at `for i in range n:`.

I looked through all the for and while loop and if else condition statements making sure that each one had ':'. However, despite finding no missing ':', the compilation clearly indicates that I have missed it somewhere. I am hoping that it would not be the same for others.

Comment: for i in range(n)

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be missing brackets around the n. In Python 3 (if that is what you are using) it should be:

```
for i in range(n):
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this

```
for i in range(n):
    #rest of the code
```

I think you are getting the error because you missed the parenthesis `()`

Answer (score 1):

> the error comes because u didn't enclosed the n in brackets

```
for i in range(n):
```